# I want to connect my salesforce for POST services to an external system using my server

Tags: integration, administration, developer

I am getting 'Service Not Available  -  503'. But when I try with postman, it working fine. I have also update remote site access as well.
Please specify if some setting needed regarding IP or something. I from Asian region, input if there are server setting needed for IP ? need to add salesforce IP  to server or register IP ? anything like that ?

Comment: To clarify, you are trying to callout from Salesforce to an externally hosted service with a POST request? A Service Not Available response would be coming from your remote server. It might be that you need to whitelist the Salesforce servers on the remote end.

Comment: Yes, Your understanding is right on path. 
I am already on that page, but cant figure out which IP should I whitelist on remote server ? there are many given on Asian Pesific section ? Where to get my org/license IP to register ? for all users.

Comment: Thanks @DanielBallinger 
It works with whitelist. I Just whitelist all the available IP ranges for Asian region and it works. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please refer this help doc for IP Ranges and to understand best practices and why we need to do it. https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000003652&type=1&sfdcIFrameOrigin=null

Comment: Thanks for your input. 
I was already on that page.